# Does the last digits of the build n° matter when rooting?

Tags: android, root

So i want to root my SM-A510F using CF-Auto-Rot, the thing is, the root file for my phone is made for the build N° of `MMB29K.A510FXXU4BQD1`, while my phone has the build N° of `MMB29K.A510FXXU4BQC1` (the second last character changes[*C* / *D*]).
Would that make the procedure fail? This phone is new and i really wouldn't want to brick it.

Comment: Yes, even a single character in the build number makes a difference. After all it's a different version, that may not be right for your device.
Quick note: be careful about the tools you are using, some of this "automatic" rooting sofware may do some shady things with your phone - espescially once it's rooted.

Comment: btw, check this out: https://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/general/twrp-3-0-0-0-galaxy-a52016-sm-a510f-t3313781
xda developers is a better place to ask questions about rooting

Comment: Questions like this one are not welcomed here. The better place for such questions is indeed xda-developers